# Firebase + GTM Tracking

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

My goal is to have App Data in Firebase Analytics, and other custom data plus app data in Google Universal Analytics.

My question is if I install Firebase SDK and GTM SDK on my App.

Does GTM handle all the data push to analytics. So with Firebase and GTM installed, will the firebase analytics automatically pick up the event tracking without going through GTM. Or when GTM is installed, everythign has to go through GTM.

For example, if I configure GTM to push data into Firebase Analytics, then will the data in Firebase Analytics be doubled up? Since GTM is pushing data and Firebase is automatically pushing data into Firebase Analytics.

Same App Event -> Firebase SDK -> Firebase Analytics (automatic)

Same App Event -> Firebase SDK -> GTM SDK -> Firebase Analytics (gtm container configured)

Same App Event ->Firebase SDK -> GTM SDK -> Google Analytics (gtm container configured)

First two will be doubled up? Is that right? Does that mean I dont need the gtm container configuration for Firebase analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through my experience, if you only want Firebase Analytics, you only need to install the Firebase SDK but if you want to then send that data to Google Analytics, you need GTM to send that data via a configured container.

Same App Event ->Firebase SDK -> GTM SDK -> Google Analytics (gtm container configured)

As an example, we have implemented Google Analytics extensively on our site to collect web data but we are utilizing Firebase (essentially as a data layer) to collect mobile app data and GTM to then send that data to Google Analytics.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a small comment here - the Firebase SDK and Firebase+GTM SDK have no "data layer" as people from the GTM world used to understand that term. There is no way (except user properties) to persist data between events

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Google Analytics, you don't need to use GTM. You can track events in Firebase Analytics itself using Firebase SDK as well as you can track customized events.

If I configure GTM to push data into Firebase Analytics, then will the data in Firebase Analytics be doubled up?
Answer: Yes, if you trigger the same event from GTM as well. You will see the events twice in Firebase Analytics as one would be triggered from GTM always with the events which happen. If this issue is what you come through, try not triggering the events from GTM.